# Why Gauss Siedel uses less memory than Gauss Elimination

Tags: memory-management, matrix, numerical-methods

I am studying numerical methods from Steven C. Charpa's book. The book says "Gauss-Siedel uses less memory than Gauss-Elimination because it does not stores "0" values in matrix", however the algorithm, written in the book, handle same matrix as Gauss Elimination. I didn't understand how Gauss-Siedel uses less memory. I searched this issue on internet people say same thing but nobody explain how.

Note: I can share algorithm in book, if won't be problem about Copyrights.

Comment: Hard to tell without actually seeing the context. *"Gauss-Siedel uses less memory than Gauss-Elimination because it does not stores `0` values in matrix"* It sounds like sparse matrix vs. dense matrix storage but I can only repeat myself: Without the context, it is hard to tell what's going on. Gauss elimination is a direct method, Gauss-Seidel is an iterative. Both can be applied to sparse matrices, so it's not necessary to store `0` values in the matrix with Gauss elimination either. It again suggests that the quoted sentence would need more context.

Comment: More from book(it's not english i am translating it): "If matrix is too big and sparse elimination methods stores "0" values unnecessarily. If matrix is not band matrix there is no way to avoid this situation." Actually my problem is not about comparing these two methods. I am trying to understand how gauss-siedel doesn't store zeros. I can't understand this from reading algortihm. Algorithm processes full matrix.

Comment: Neither method has to store `0` values if a sparse matrix format is used. I would suggest a better book on sparse matrix computations. It is old but still good: [Direct Methods for Sparse Matrices](http://www.amazon.com/Methods-Matrices-Monographs-Numerical-Analysis/dp/0198534213).

Answer (score 0):

The Gauss-Elimination method has to store zeros while computing. This is because in the course of elimination of lower triangular matrix, the zeros can become non-zero values. On the other hand the Gauss-Siedel method, if written to handle sparse matrices, can only operate on non-zero values.

In simple way you can say that Gauss-Siedel method works on one equation at a time, solving  for i^{th} variable with non-zero coefficient, therefore it can easily skip the terms with zero coefficient.

Gauss-Elimination works on complete matrix making all the coefficients below the i^{th} coefficient zero, but in the process the coefficients in the upper triangular matrix are changed. I think that there is no easy way of writing Gauss-Elimination method for sparse matrices.